# MVC... how and why, and what other good options are there (PHP)?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

All the examples I've seen of what and how MVC SHOULD be have used classes as the models, classes as the controller, and HTML templates as the view. And all of them consisted of one index.php script and different requests in the url to run the entire site.

So they've all been something like...

```
MODEL
class User{
    function getUser($userID){
      $sql = mysql_query('SELECT name......');
      // more code.....
      return $array
    }
}

VIEW
<h2><?php echo $user['name']; ?></h2>

CONTROLLER
class Controller{
    $userModel = new User;
    $userInfo = $userModel->getUser($id);

    $template = new Template('usertemplate.tpl');
    $template->setVariables($userInfo);
    $template->display();
}
```

I understand why the model is made of classes that simply get and save data (even though I assume classes arent always necessary and functions could be used). I understand why the template consists of mainly HTML. But I dont understand why the controller is a class. I would assume the controller to be a procedural script (like userprofile.php which gets the users data from the model and sends it to the template for displaying).

Also, I was wondering why every tutorial I've read dealt with mod rewriting, and using a single page with requests in the url like "index.php?user=1", or index.php?news=3 to run the entire site. Whats wrong with having separate pages like user_profile.php?id=1, or news.php?id=3...

Can somebody please help me with a quick "tutorial" and an explanation along the way. Like...how would a registration form be implemented using MVC, what would go where and why? thankyou

PS. what other kind of design patterns are there

Comment: well, at least Samstyle PHP Framework does not use classes for Controllers. instead, it's just normal PHP scripts http://code.google.com/p/samstyle-php-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big "win" of the controller in PHP's version of MVC is you get away from having a separate PHP page for each and every URL that your application responds to.

When you have a new single page being created for each URL, you're expecting your developers (or yourself) to pull in the needed libraries and initialize the template/layout engine in the same way.  Even when you're a single developer, the temptation to break from the "standard" way of doing things usually ends up being too strong, which means **each URL/PHP-page ends up being its own mini-application** instead of each URL/PHP-page being part of the same application.  When you have multiple developers this is guarantied to happen.

The end results is pages and components that don't play nice with each other and are hard to debug (with everything hanging out in the global namespace), giving an inconsistent experience for both the users and the developers who have to work on the project.

MVC frameworks also make it easier to give your site friendly URLs. There's usually enough going on in the routing system that you don't **need** to resort to a huge number of query string variables.  Readable URLs are a plus, for SEO and for savvy users.

Finally, although this is pie in the sky with most shops, when you have a controller the methods on the controller become easily unit testable.  While you can technically wrap a test harness around a non-MVC site, it's always a pain in the ass, and never works like you'd like it to.

Answer (score 1):

> using a single page with requests in
>   the url like "index.php?user=1", or
>   index.php?news=3 to run the entire
>   site. Whats wrong with having separate
>   pages like user_profile.php?id=1, or
>   news.php?id=3...

Using a single entry point makes some things easier, I suppose :

- You don't have to duplicate any portion of code in user_profile.php and news.php
- If you want to set up any kind of filter (like PHPIDS for security, or ACL, for instance), you only have one file to modify, and it's done for the whole application.

> PS. what other kind of design patterns
>   are there

There are a lot of design patterns ; you can find a list on the [Design pattern (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) article on wikipedia, for instance -- with links to the page of each one of them, for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having separate scripts for each action, and in fact you CAN create a MVC architecture this way, without using a class for the controller. I'm working on an MVC framework at the moment that supports both styles.

The important thing is really to keep separation of different concerns. Database logic goes in your models, Layout logic goes in templates, and everything else in the controller.

So for a really simple example you could have a script "register.php" with the following code

```
$signup_options = SignupOptions::getSignupOptions(); // Load some data      
require("register_form.php");  // Pass it to the view
```

And this posts to register_process.php

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$email    = $_REQUEST['email'];
Users::Register( $username, $password, $email );
header( 'location: register_success.php' );
```

MVC is not suitable for all applications, so you should consider your architecture on a per project basis. For many sites, just having a bunch of independent scripts works fine. For larger more complex applications however, MVC has proven itself to be a reliable and scalable way of developing web applications.

Another common design pattern is "View-Helper", which is where you call a template directly, and the template calls a "Helper" object that performs business logic between the template and the models. Similar in concept, but you can skip having any extra code for templates that don't need it, while still maintaining separation of concerns like MVC. (The difference is essentially that you call the template directly, rather than calling a controller).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement a good application, but I am just going to touch on a few concepts. These concepts are taken from Samstyle PHP Framework.

Firstly, you have these components: Model ([Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)), View, View Controller and Backend Controller.

This View Controller actually controls how the view is going to be like (e.g. display out the registration form). The Backend Controller processes user data on the backend and interacts with the Model (database).

So here we can easily integrate [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) into it.

Say you have *register.php* for the View Controller which will display the form and parse the content into the template HTML file.

User uses the form, submit and will then be posted to the Backend Controller *deck.php*. The Backend Controller validates, check then passes the data to functions (Table Data Gateway) which will help you to interact with the database. After the interaction is done, the user is redirected either to a success page, or the registration page with an error.

In the Model (Table Data Gateway), you actually have functions which take in an array and then CRUD with the database.